# json data not showing up in morris bar

Tags: jquery, morris.js

i am storing the Json data into a variable and calling this data into a Morris.Bar function in jquery,by doing so i am geting undefined data and unable to show graph
Below is my code.Have a look and please help me its really important.

```
  var datajson='{"x":"sales", "y":"46146","z":"46146","a":"46146"},{"x":"swami", "y":"460104","z":"460104","a":"460104"},';

var  content = JSON.stringify(datajson); 
var parsedContent = JSON.parse(content);

if (typeof Morris != 'undefined') {
                        Morris.Bar({

                            data : [parsedContent], 
                                element : 'chart31',
                                axes : true,
                                xkey : 'x',
                                ykeys : [ 'y', 'z', 'a' ],
                                labels : [ 'Quotation amount ', 'Purchase order amount ', 'Invoice amount' ],
                                barColors : [ 'red', 'blue', 'green' ]
                            });
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data does not parse.  You have a js error - check your console:

```
var datajson='{"x":"sales", "y":"46146","z":"46146","a":"46146"},{"x":"swami", "y":"460104","z":"460104","a":"460104"},';
```

Should be:

```
var datajson='[{"x":"sales", "y":"46146","z":"46146","a":"46146"},{"x":"swami", "y":"460104","z":"460104","a":"460104"}]';
```

And then change:

```
data: parsedContent,
```

Comment: It does work.  I fixed it for you here: http://jsbin.com/fapotoboquyi/1/edit?js,output